# the route does not support the get method, it supports post method

Tags: laravel, http-headers

When I enter the screen to add data to the system I get the error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. and I can not solve it. The idea is to enter data in one screen and in another that are displayed but it does not work because of the error described above. Could you please help me.

```
Route::get('/lista',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@show',

    'as'=>'cars.show'

]);

Route::post('/crear',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@create',

    'as'=>'cars.create'

]);



public function show(){

        $cars=Car::all();

        return view ('lista',['cars'=>$cars]);

    }

  public function crear(Request $request){

        $patente=$request['patente'];

        $marca=$request['marca'];

        $modelo=$request['modelo'];

        $color=$request['color'];

        $fecha_ingreso=$request['fecha_ingreso'];

        $car=new Car();

        $car->patente=$patente;

        $car->marca=$marca;

        $car->modelo=$modelo;

        $car->color=$color;

        $car->fecha_ingreso=$fecha_ingreso;

        $car->save();

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Brief form to create

```
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>

            <form action="{{route('cars.crear')}}" method="post">

               @csrf

               <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Patente:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="patente" size="6" maxlength="6" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Marca:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="marca" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

bief form to show

table, th td{

```
                    border: 4px solid black;

                 }

                </style>

                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <caption>Lista de autos</caption>

                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

                                    <tr>

                                        <th>Patente</th>

                                        <th>Marca</th>

                                        <th>Modelo</th>

                                        <th>Color</th>

                                        <th>Fecha_ingreso</th>

                                    </tr>

                                    @foreach($cars as $car)

                                        <tr>

                                            <td>{{$car->patente}}</td>

                                            <td>{{$car->marca}}</td>

                                            <td>{{$car->modelo}}</td>

                                            <td>{{$car->color}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$car->fecha_ingreso}}</td>

                                            <td>

                                                <a href="{{ route('cars.edit', $car->id )}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Modificar</a>

                                            </td>

                                            <td>

                                                <form action="{{ route('cars.destroy', $car->id )}}" method="POST">

                                                    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">

                                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value=Eliminar>

                                                </form>

                                            </td>

                                        </tr>

                                    @endforeach

                                </table>        
                        </div>
```

Comment: What tools/libraries etc are you using?

Comment: can we see the form please?

Comment: check you form if you define method="post" or method="get"

Comment: edit post whit form

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you form is defined with a POST like so :

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are, creating get request clear, do sth like this

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/clear','uses'=>'CarController@create','as'=>'cars.create' );
```

or

```
Route::any('/clear','uses'=>'CarController@create','as'=>'cars.create' );
```

if you are creating post request with form then,

```
<form action="/clear" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: when I add Route :: match (['get', 'post'], '/clear','uses'=>'CarController@create','as'=>'cars.create' '); in my web route I get the following error "SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'patent' can not be null (SQL: insert into` cars` (`patent`,` marca`, `modelo`,` color `,` date_in ', can you help me please?

Comment: its database exception, set patent nullalbe if its not necessary, or feed some data.

Comment: What do you mean by feeding some data?

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías, use server side validation, that solve your issue, the error  clearly says that patent can not be null.